# Locating Backup folder used by Vestacp

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, vesta

From the command line, I am trying to locate the backup directory VestaCP are using to save the backup and I failed to find out.

https://snag.gy/I8Tt4z.jpg

Please help me.

I have checked the following locations

/usr/local/vesta

but no luck.

I will highly appreciate your help.

Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vestacp's backup directory is at root/backup 
then you could find the backup file .

```
$ cd /backup
```

or you could use the "find" command

```
$ sudo find / -iname "{the account that you use}*.tar"
```

E.g.：admin.2017-07-22.tar

to find where is the backup file then you will get the location

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot, VestaCP is storing the backups in the `/backup` directory on your server. Did you check this directory?

Comment: Thank you, this was my answer.